# Webscraping in Python (beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape and am currently stuck on how I should continue with the code. I am trying to create a code that scrapes the first 80 Yelp! reviews. Since there are only 20 reviews per page, I am also stuck on figuring out how to create a loop to change the webpage to the next 20 reviews.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
all_reviews = ''
def get_description(pullman):
    url = f'https://www.yelp.com/biz/pullman-bar-and-diner-iowa-city'
    # get webpage data from url
    response = requests.get(url)
    #sleep for 2 seconds
    time.sleep(2)
    # get html document from web page data
    html_doc = response.text
    # parser
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
    page_title = soup.title.text
    #get a tag content based on class
    p_tag = soup.find_all('p',class_='lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f comment__373c0__3EKjH text-color--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_')[0]
    #print the text within the tag
    return p_tag.text
```

Comment: What is the error? How are you planning to get or loop over the rest of pages?

Comment: Have you gotten the first 80 reviews? After you are done with that, find out the number of pages available. The link parameter changes for every page, so iterate through them.

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 , right now I am getting a blank return. Also, since the webpage only holds 20 reviews, I think creating a for loop would be best given that each webpage ends with the start amount of reviews you're currently on.

Comment: there are lots of existing questions on scraping yelp reviews. Also, I may be remembering incorrectly but I think they have an anti-scraping measure of returning random pages at certain points.

Answer (score 0):

General notes/tips: 
Use the "Inspect" tool on pages you want to scrape.

As for your question, its also going to work much nicer if you visit the website and parse BeautifulSoup and then use the soup object in functions - visit once, parse as many times as you want. You won't be blacklisted by websites as often this way. An example structure below.

```
url = f'https://www.yelp.com/biz/pullman-bar-and-diner-iowa-city'
# get webpage data from url
response = requests.get(url)
#sleep for 2 seconds
time.sleep(2)
# get html document from web page data
html_doc = response.text
# parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
get_description(soup)
get_reviews(soup)
```

If you inspect the page, each review appears as a copy of a template. If you take each review as an individual object and parse it, you can get the reviews you are looking for. The review template has the class id:lemon--li__373c0__1r9wz u-space-b3 u-padding-b3 border--bottom__373c0__uPbXS border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT

As for pagination, the pagination numbers are contained in a template with class="lemon--div__373c0__1mboc pagination-links__373c0__2ZHo6 border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT nowrap__373c0__1_N1j"

The individual page number links are contained within a-href tags, so just write a for loop to iterate over the links.

Answer (score 0):

To get the next page, you're going to have to follow the "Next" link. The problem here is that the link is just the same as before plus `#`. Open the Inspector [Ctrl-Shift-I in Chrome, Firefox] and switch to the network tab, then click the next button, you'll see a request to something like:

`https://www.yelp.com/biz/U4mOl3TRbaJ9-bgTQ1d6fw/review_feed?rl=en&sort_by=relevance_desc&q=&start=40`

which looks something like:

`{"reviews": [{"comment": {"text": "Such a great experience every time you come into this place`...

This is JSON. The only problem is that you'll need to fool Yelp's servers into thinking you're browsing the website, by sending their headers to them, otherwise you get different data that doesn't look like comments.

They look like this in Chrome

[image: Yelp Headers in Chrome]

My usual approach is to copy-paste the headers not prefixed with a colon (ignore `:authority`, etc) directly into a triple-quoted string called `raw_headers`, then run

`headers = dict([[h.partition(':')[0], h.partition(':')[2]] for h in raw_headers.split('\n')])`

over them, and pass them as an argument to requests with:

`requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

Some of the headers won't be necessary, cookies might expire, and all sorts of other issues might arise but this at least gives you a fighting chance.